# Postgres role granted but getting permission denied for relation error

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-web-services, permissions, amazon-rds

I am trying to create a write-only role for a data collection endpoint.

My design plan had been:

1. create the write-only role,
2. assign a user to that role,
3. let the application behind the endpoint use that role

---

I have created the role

```
CREATE ROLE new_write_only WITH
   NOLOGIN
   NOSUPERUSER
   INHERIT
   NOCREATEDB
   NOCREATEROLE
   NOREPLICATION
```

I have created the user

```
CREATE USER " + user_name + "
   VALID UNTIL 'infinity'
   ENCRYPTED PASSWORD '" + password + "'
```

I assign the user to the role

```
GRANT new_write_only TO " + user_name + "
```

And I assign `INSERT` rights to the role

```
GRANT INSERT ON target_table TO new_write_only
```

---

But when I run the below as `user_name`

```
INSERT INTO target_table (col_1, col_2, col_3) VALUES ('123abc', '{}', '2018-02-22 10:45:01.845539')
```

I get

```
permission denied for relation target_table
```

When I run the same as the table owner, no problem.

Comment: is it aws rds?.. did you run all statements as superuser?

Comment: yes it is the aws rds postgres engine

Comment: so you have to run `GRANT INSERT ON target_table TO new_write_only` as relation owner then

Comment: I am `GRANT`ing logged in as the table owner, and I am not getting an error on my `GRANT` statement - so I think that is okay? Maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: if you granting as owner - should be ok I believe. alas I can't think how to reproduce it... all in public schema? btw

Comment: Yes, public schema

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to `GRANT USAGE` on the `sequence` as well

```
GRANT USAGE ON SEQUENCE target_table_row_id_seq TO new_write_only;
```

Comment: to fix the `permission denied for relation target_table`?